# Cassandra row cache not reducing query latency

Tags: database, caching, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I have a table with partition key + clustering column, and I enabled row caching = 2000. I gave row caching 20GB by changing the yaml file.

I can see that my hit rate is ~90% (which is good enough for me), but monitoring shows no latency reduction at all (it's even a bit higher after caching). Note that the query that I'm running is to get all rows for a given partition key. Number of rows differ from 10 to 10000.

Any idea why Cassandra row caching is not effective for my case?

Host: EC2 r4.16x, which has 64 cores and 488GB memory.

C* version: 3.11.0

=========nodetool info=========:

ID                     : 1f05c846-ddd6-4409-8473-10f3c0490279

Gossip active          : true

Thrift active          : false

Native Transport active: true

Load                   : 145.95 GiB

Generation No          : 1506984130

Uptime (seconds)       : 69561

Heap Memory (MB)       : 4707.58 / 7987.25

Off Heap Memory (MB)   : 680.54

Data Center            : us-east

Rack                   : 1e

Exceptions             : 0

Key Cache              : entries 671231, size 100 MiB, capacity 100 MiB, 
558160978 hits, 566196579 requests, 0.986 recent hit rate, 14400 save 
period in seconds

Row Cache              : entries 1225796, size 17.8 GiB, capacity 19.53 GiB, 80015143 hits, 86502918 requests, 0.925 recent hit rate, 0 save period in seconds

Counter Cache          : entries 0, size 0 bytes, capacity 50 MiB, 0 hits, 0 requests, NaN recent hit rate, 7200 save period in seconds

Chunk Cache            : entries 122880, size 480 MiB, capacity 480 MiB, 334907479 misses, 6940124103 requests, 0.952 recent hit rate, 13.407 microseconds miss latency

Percent Repaired       : 85.28384276963543%

Token                  : (invoke with -T/--tokens to see all 256 tokens)

Comment: How much memory is the row cache using now (can check with 'nodetool info')? How often do the rows change (how often are you invalidating the row cache)? The system you're using is atypical - cassandra is designed for more smaller machines, not a few huge machines like that.

Comment: Are GCs impacted by change to enable? What heap settings do you have?

Comment: @JeffJirsa Right now I'm using the big machine to do prototype, will switch to smaller ones if this works. The cache was consuming spaces, I saw it was using 13/20GB at one point. The rows are updated not so frequently, mostly adding new rows. And the read pattern is to get all rows of a partition if rows are updated & added.

Comment: @ChrisLohfink The heap is 8GB, but I never see it using close to that. GC stats looks okay

Comment: You are trying to reduce read latency.  If the cache is being hit but is not reducing latency, the bottleneck must be somewhere else.  Not enough info here to troubleshoot, but would start looking at the issue more comprehensively, and work through possible bottlenecks.

Comment: @ChrisGerlt Thanks. I agree with you - I was looking at CPU Memory DiskIO NetworkIO, nothing was hitting the maximum. Any other tips on how to identify the bottleneck?